# Centralized error reporting in PHP

Tags: php, error-reporting

is there a way to handle error reporting in a centralized manner in PHP? I'd like to be notified of all errors raised by my application by email.

What's the best way to achieve this for a whole application?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Kalium mentioned, you'll want to be using [`set_error_handler`](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), but that only gets you part of the way. You also want to trap uncaught exceptions. For that, use [`set_exception_handler`](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).

What I do myself is have my code trap errors, and convert those errors to approprate exceptions that I can catch elsewhere. For anything that isn't caught, I use the default exception handler to log and report them, and to display an appropriate error if necessary.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to handle errors at runtime any way you like.

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 types of errors:

1. System errors, such as warnings or fatal errors raised by PHP. 404 errors are also in this category.
2. Database errors by a malformed or failed query or database connection.
3. Logical errors such as when something went wrong in the internal working of your application not related to a server or database. For example if you expected a certain file to be in a given folder, but it wasn't.

The best way to create an `ErrorHandler` class that handles all three types of errors. For  system errors, you would use `set_error_handler` or read up on one of the online tutorials such as [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ref_error.asp).

For database, I suggest using a centralized Database class which handles all the queries. Use something like this:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if (! $result)
{
   $ErrorHandler->dbError(mysql_error(), $sql);
}
```

For logical errors, such as the error of not finding an expected file or database record, you would call up the same ErrorHandler class and do something like:

```
if ($logicalError)
{
   $ErrorHandler->appError('Something bad happened',__LINE__, __FILE__);
   $ErrorHandler->showAppErrorPage();
}
```

Here the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` constants will give exactly the location where this error occurred. Read up on them on the [php.net](http://php.net) site.

Your `ErrorHandler` class can log all errors to a log file, email you, or even SMS/Text you on your mobile. It could also be used to redirect the user to an error page.